# How I can add edited images to ListView from a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview, mvvm

I have an app with simple MVVM implementation with ListView on my View.

I need to add images to ListView, but not just images. I need to draw something on that images.

I have a model which consists of filepath, middle and theta properties. And I need somehow to bind edited images to ListView.

What is the proper way to accomplish that? How I can add edited images to ListView from a ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit the images in C# code before adding them to a collection that is used in  binding
2. Edit the DataTemplate and overlay each image with XAML Path geometry
3. Other options?

It's really not easy to answer because you don't state *how* you plan to edit the image...

Comment: I need to draw semitransparent layers on image. And I didn't think about overlaying images with DataTemplate. I assume that should work.

Comment: No. You use a `DataTemplate` on your `ItemsControl` to define how to represent the style of each item in the list. Within that template you can overlay the actual item with something else.